# How to configure doorkeeper without oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, doorkeeper

I am learning how to develop API for rails app. I am trying to develop it to use for mobile app. So far I developed an small api for most of the controller. But I am having problem with login. I am using devise for user management and rails 4.1.

I watched railscast video for [doorkeeper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper) implementation .  But in the video they used doorkeeper with oauth gem. I want to implement it without oauth. How can I do that?

So far I added `doorkeeper gem` and in `initialize` folder added `doorkeeper.rb` with following code

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id]) || redirect_to(login_url)
  end
end
```

And added `before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!` in a controller

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CoursesController < ApplicationController
      #before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
      before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      respond_to :json


      # GET /courses/1
      # GET /courses/1.json
      def show
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
        @assignment = @course.assignments
        respond_with @assignment
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now when I hit this link on browser

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/courses/5
```

I get no output but in console get this

```
Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

And If I comment out `before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!` in the controller I get json output with expected data. So how can I configure doorkeeper and make this work?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you would need to authenticate the user to the API first, after which you would receive an OAuth access token. There's multiple flows (= ways of getting an access token) all listed in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3). You would then use said access token in subsequent requests to request the resource. Normally you would put this token in the Authorization header of the request.

Right now you're counting on a session variable session[:user_id], which doesn't exist, so it leads to `:doorkeeper_authorize!` redirecting, ending the chain, thus resulting in a 401 Unauthorized response from Doorkeeper.

If, in your case, you wish to authenticate with the user's credentials, as per [section 1.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4), you would need to configure Doorkeeper for that. [See the wiki](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow).

I hope this gets you going.